# Gradle project refresh failed : Error:Cause: invalid CEN header (bad signature) in android studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I had to reformat my computer, and re install the windows. after I also install the Java and android studio also. then Environment variables also set correctly but i can not make a project using android studio, when i trying to create a project a got **Error:Cause: invalid CEN header (bad signature)** in message gradle sync console. is any one got faced this situation before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come across the same error, this error happened when unzip the gradle-1.xx-all.zip, you need to re-download or use `-unzip` cmd to have a try, good luck!